# how to add physics to the SceneKit scene?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, physics

Hey I have a scene kit scene and my goal is just to get the guy/character on the scene to fall do to gravity and then hit the floor. Thats it. the "Guy" is simple a node .scn node. and the ground is a also a .scn scene as shown in the code below. Ive gotten as far as the skills I have to try and add simple physics to the scene. I know how to add physics perfectly in SPRITEKIT but the .scn nodes don't let me attach the same variable that would use give the character physics. There are no errors in this code But the character is not affect by gravity when ran Thanks

Code:

```
   // Collision bit masks
  let BitmaskCollision        = 1 << 2
  let BitmaskCollectable      = 1 << 3
  let BitmaskEnemy            = 1 << 4
  let BitmaskFriend           = 1 << 5
  let BitmaskOutofBounds      = 1 << 6

  class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate{

// The character
let character = Character()

// The Playing Fields
let FieldScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/TesingCampusField.dae")!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.scene = FieldScene
    scnView.playing = true
    scnView.delegate = self
    scnView.scene!.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    //-----Adding Gravity----------------------------------------------
    scnView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -9.8)
    //------Add-the-Character-to-Scene--------------------
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(character.node)

     }
```

End Of code for this Controller
The Character is simply being set up from a file called "Character"

```
class Character {

let node = SCNNode()

init() {
    let GuyScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Guy.scn")
    let characterTopLevelNode: SCNNode = GuyScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Guy", recursively: true)!
    node.addChildNode(characterTopLevelNode)


   characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BitmaskEnemy    
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BitmaskCollision
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BitmaskCollectable
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

    // Below is the Creation of the Physics body of the character
    let (min, max) = node.boundingBox
    let collisionCapsuleRadius = CGFloat(max.x - min.x) * 0.4
    let collisionCapsuleHeight = CGFloat(max.y - min.y)
    let characterCollisionNode = SCNNode()
    characterCollisionNode.name = "collider"

    // position light above the floor so you dont hit it and cause a contact
    characterCollisionNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, collisionCapsuleHeight * 0.51, 0.0)
    characterCollisionNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape:SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCapsule(capRadius: collisionCapsuleRadius, height: collisionCapsuleHeight), options:nil))
    // Adding the Pysics body of the character called "characterCollisionNode" to the actually character
    node.addChildNode(characterCollisionNode)
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an earlier version of this question [Applying simple Physics to a .scn object in SceneKit XCODE SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648718/applying-simple-physics-to-a-scn-object-in-scenekit-xcode-swift/38648857#38648857)

And the answer is probably similar, you don't appear to be adding the `node` as a child of the scene.

Comment: Yea it turns out that i was trying to add the child to the scene before the actual 3D view was being created because i put the add child code on the very top of my viewdidload