# Applying simple Physics to a .scn object in SceneKit XCODE SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

Hey Below I have a normal sphere that I created just to test if my in game scene/world has physics. So I simply put the ball in the scene/world and it is perfect. It is affected by the gravity. So then I try to do the exact same thing to the .scn file. I give it physics the same as the test sphere that falls down do to gravity. but the man doesn't move. The gravity is set to -9.8 to simulate regular gravity 
Code:

```
  //----Test-Circle-here--------------------

    var sphere1: SCNNode!
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 10.5)
    let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    let collisionCapsuleRadius = CGFloat(0.4 - 0.4) * 0.4
    let collisionCapsuleHeight = CGFloat(0.4 - 0.4)
    sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
    sphereGeometry.materials = [sphereMaterial]
    sphere1 = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphere1.position = SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 0.05, z: 0.05)

    //----Giving it a physics---------

    sphere1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    sphere1.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    sphere1.physicsBody?.restitution = 1 //bounceness of the object
    sphere1.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1 // rotationess
    sphere1.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape:SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCapsule(capRadius: collisionCapsuleRadius, height: collisionCapsuleHeight), options:nil))
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere1)
```

Below the man Stays in same- spot no matter what some how

```
     class Character {

let node = SCNNode()
init() {

    let GuyScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/FoxMan2.scn")
    let characterTopLevelNode: SCNNode = GuyScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Guy", recursively: true)!
    let collisionCapsuleRadius = CGFloat(0.4 - 0.4) * 0.4
    let collisionCapsuleHeight = CGFloat(0.4 - 0.4)
    characterTopLevelNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 10.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)

    //----Giveing it a physics---------

    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 1 //bounceness of the object
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1 // rotationess
    characterTopLevelNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape:SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCapsule(capRadius: collisionCapsuleRadius, height: collisionCapsuleHeight), options:nil))
    node.addChildNode(characterTopLevelNode)

 }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB14Z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWK7t.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that your `characterTopLevelNode` is actually the node you think it is (name mismatches are pretty common).  That's often the problem in these kinds of situations.  You seem to be adding the `characterTopLevelNode` as a child of `node` but never adding `node` as a child of the scene being displayed.

One other thing,  don't set the options on the physics body before you create the physics body.

For example: 

`sphere1.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, ...
sphere1.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true
sphere1.physicsBody.friction = 0
sphere1.physicsBody.restitution = 1
sphere1.physicsBody.angularDamping = 1`